# Confirming endpoints were deleted in SageMaker notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm just testing out AWS Sagemaker notebook and created an endpoint using a partial script below:

```
endpoint_name = 'engine' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
endpoint_config_name = 'engine_config' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
model_name = 'engine_model' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

while status=='Creating':
    time.sleep(60)
    resp = sm_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = resp['EndpointStatus']
    print("Status: " + status)
```

I'm trying to remove that endpoint by using:
sm_client.delete_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)

However, it didn't work because I naively used timestamps for the endpoint_name and I didn't remember them. The original variable values were overriden when I re-run the code. As a result, I can't delete the existing endpoint.
I went to the Sagemaker management dashboard --> inference --> endpoints, but it's empty. I don't even know if I'm currently having any active endpoints or not. Please advise how to delete my endpoint in this case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there somewhere in the script where you call the `CreateEndpoint()` method? Are the top 3 lines in the same Jupyter cell as the `while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If there are no endpoints active under the "Endpoints" tab in the SageMaker service console, then you will not be incurring any charges for inference or endpoint infrastructure.**

If this is the case, your Endpoints tab should look like the following:
[image]

**Endpoint Configurations**, on the other hand, involve the metadata necessary for an endpoint deployment. This is just the metadata, and are stored (without cost) in your account, visible in the console under the "Endpoint Configurations" tab. You do not need to remove these configurations when tearing down an endpoint.

**Important note:** Double check that you are checking in the console for the *region you would have deployed to*. For example, if you ran the notebook and deployed an endpoint in `us-east-1`, but check the SageMaker console for `us-west-2`, it would not be displaying endpoints from the other region.

Comment: You're a life saver. I use both ohio and virginia and didn't pay attention that my management console was in the wrong region. When I made the switch, there are so many active endpoints lol